# showing jquery datepicker within jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

so I have datepicker working just fine in a normal window but I cannot
for the life of me get it to work within a dialog.

I have some javascript that opens a dialog in my application.js file
as well as the datepicker js
is as follows:

```
$(function() {
 $("#version_release_date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.popup').click(function() {
   $('<div />').appendTo('body').load($(this).attr('href') + '
form').dialog({
           title: $(this).text()
           })
   });
   return false;
 });
});
```

now the first function works fine if I just go straight to that page
but if the page is rendered via the second function in a dialog the
datepicker no longer appears.

this is where the dialog is created:

```
<%= link_to 'Close Escalation', new_version_path, :class => 'popup' %>
```

these are my includes

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css", "application" %>

 <%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js", "application" %>

 <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.rails.js" %>
```

any help is appreciated.    basically from what I can tell I can't get
any javascript to work in the dialog.

I even tried adding the script to the page but that didn't work
either.

This is inside a rails app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/LabRT/)

```
<div id="mydialog"></div>
<a href="/url/" class="popup">title text</a>
```

and jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('a.popup').click(function(event) {
        // prevent link from going to href
        event.preventDefault();

        // empty the contents of the dialog and load new content 
        $('#mydialog').empty().load($(this).attr('href') + 'form');

        /*apply datepicker  to input , i'm assuming this gets loaded in the above line if not dont' put it here 
            if its the documet and not loaded you don't want to apply it multiple times
            */
        $("#version_release_date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});

        //set the title of the dialog
        $('#mydialog').dialog('option', 'title', this.text);\

        //open the dialog
        $('#mydialog').dialog('open');
    });

    //setup the dialog but don't open it yet
    $('#mydialog').dialog({autoOpen: false});
});
```

Comment: hmmm   there is nothing in the dialog when I click title text in the demo.

Comment: right because it would load the href but I don't have an href to load

Comment: I am trying to get it to work  now.   will post more on my tests shortly.    first thing I noticed is there are 2 #'s before version_release_date   I assume that is  a typo?

Comment: almost there.   I have it working but only if I put the script directly on my page.   does not work from the application.js file

Comment: I will keep playing with it.    Also I am not understanding why I had to add the div with the input field to the calling page?  but also this input field appears not to actually show on that page either.  I am not understanding the javascript I guess.

Comment: finally got it all working I needed to stick it into the document ready part of the application.js file and it started working.   I would like to understand why we have to stick the div on the source page.   I am not understanding that part of the solution although it seems to work